# How do I call a constructor with arguments for types instantiated in a boost fusion container?

Tags: c++, boost

Here is a simple example which illustrates the issue:

```
// this class requires a parameter to its constructor
class A
{
  A() = delete;
  A(int x) {}
};

using B = A;
using C = A;

using Vector = boost::fusion::vector<A, B, C>;

// somewhere else in my code
template <typename FusionVector>
void fun()
{
  // I need to instantiate this vector here, and initialise each element with some integer.
  // I _know_ what parameters the types take, but I have no idea what types they are
  // or how many of them there are. Can I do this?

  FusionVector vec; // this won't work...
}

int main()
{
  int x = 10; // I want to construct all types in Vector with this value

  fun<Vector>(); // how do I do that?
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I know what parameters the types take"? Where do you get those parameters from? Do all constructors take exactly one argument?

Comment: How can you know the parameters without knowing their type ? How do you access those parameters ?

Comment: I know that the types, in this example, take one `int` type as parameter to their constructor. I create the values that I pass as parameters but I don't know what the type that I am instantiating is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the commenters said, the question arises where you'll get the values from. Now, I assumed you mean you know what values to pass for "default" construction (even though there is not, technically, a default constructor).

For this purpose, you can use a trait:

```
namespace mytraits {
    template <typename T>
    struct elem_construct { 
        static T call() { return T(); } 
    };
}
```

As you can see, the default implementation of `elem_construct::call` just calls the default constructor **<sup>[1]</sup>**.

---

Now, how to invoke this trait for each vector element?

In a perfect world (read: where Boost Fusion was using variadics in true C++11 style), it would be simple

```
template <typename FusionVector> struct fun_helper;

template <typename... Ts>
    struct fun_helper<boost::fusion::vector<Ts...> > {
        static typename boost::fusion::vector<Ts...> call() { 
            return { std::move(mytraits::elem_construct<Ts>::call())... }; 
        }
    };
```

However, this fails on the reason that Boost Fusion supports C++03 and there are no true variadics. Therefore, 10 **<sup>[2]</sup>** template arguments are deduced, and we would end up passing 3 `A` instances *as well as* 7 instances of type `boost::fusion::void_`... Yeah. That doesn't really work.

So jumping through some hoops to placate the compiler:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename... Ts>
        struct internal_fun_helper {
            static typename boost::fusion::vector<Ts...> call() {
                return boost::fusion::vector<Ts...> (std::move(mytraits::elem_construct<Ts>::call())...);
            }
        };

    // helpers that detect the real cardinality of vectors even in the presence of C++03 faux variadics
    // {{{ plumbing
    template <typename FusionVector> struct fun_helper;

    template <typename T1>
        struct fun_helper<boost::fusion::vector<T1> > {
            static typename boost::fusion::vector<T1> call() { return internal_fun_helper<T1>::call(); }
        };

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
        struct fun_helper<boost::fusion::vector<T1,T2> > {
            static typename boost::fusion::vector<T1,T2> call() { return internal_fun_helper<T1,T2>::call(); }
        };

    // etc. - you get the idea
```

Now you can just dispatch the specializations using `fun`:

```
template <typename FusionVector> FusionVector fun() {
    return detail::fun_helper<FusionVector>::call();
}
```

And it all works, see this demo **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69f4fe56191496eb)**

```
// here's the magic that tells our `fun` factory how to construct A
namespace mytraits {
    template <>
    struct elem_construct<A> { static A call() { return A(42); } };
}

#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;

int main()
{
    boost::fusion::for_each(fun<boost::fusion::vector<A, B, C>>(), std::cout << arg1 << "\n");
}
```

Printing out

```
A[42]
A[42]
A[42]
```

---

**<sup>[1]</sup>** (or value initializes T for primitive types and aggregates).

**<sup>[2]</sup>** depending on preprocessor defines, but 10 is the default limit (see **[`FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/vector.html)**)

Comment: Thanks sehe. How would this look if I want to use a non-default constructor, taking, for example, and integer as parameter (I edited my question to make this clearer)?

Comment: @quant my example already shows this. (Read my first paragraph?) Note that `A` does not _have_ a default constructor. Indeed I took this from your example. I took it you didn't just want to know how to forward arguments: **[that seems a little too easy](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/480c8e31d83c4e54)**

Comment: Oh, reading the update of your question, it seems you want to replace the number `42` by `10` in the trait specialization.